# can't run catkin_make on ros-fuerte

Tags: catkin-make, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros-fuerte. The package 'ros-fuerte-catkin' is installed. But I cannot build my application using catkin_make:

```
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
source /usr/share/drcsim/setup.sh
catkin_make: command not found
```

when I'm trying to install:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-catkin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ros-fuerte-catkin is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62960/can%27t-run-catkin_make-on-ros-fuerte/) by [cupuyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/4919/cupuyc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-05-17**:
I'm not familiar with catkin on Fuerte, but the wiki [says](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin#Install_prebuilt_package):

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-05-17**:
*Note for ROS Fuerte Users: An experimental version of catkin was released with ROS Fuerte that is quite different from the version in Groovy. Those using ROS Fuerte should continue utilizing rosbuild*.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-05-17**:
So it may not has this functionality at all, i.e. `catkin_make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I recall correctly, Fuerte did not yet have catkin, therefore catkin_make does not work. Try rosmake, assuming you have rospackages.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-19**:
Fuerte had an early version of catkin, but I don't think `catkin_make` was available.